# Option to add new contact freezes up - won't work

Tags: contacts, profile, upgrade

Can anyone help? I just upgraded CiviCRM and have been having problems since. I cleared cache and cookies and that helped with a bit but now we have issues with clicking on **Creating a new contact** -- I'm unable to open address details or anything beyond contact details. The page freezes up when I try. I contacted our hosting (CiviHosting) but they haven't been helpful.

Here's what they said:

> Yes, I see it now. The issue is a JavaScript error: uncaught
>   exception: Missing number at position 0 which appears to be a problem
>   with the jQuery date picker, but I am not actually familiar with this
>   issue and I haven't seen it before. My guess is that there is an issue
>   with one of your WordPress plugins or your theme. The first step to
>   test would be to disable the plugins and change the theme. CiviCRM
>   itself is known to work, so the issue is something else. Thank you.
>
> Ref-Mid: $JmoAAA==$405212bbaf@2b6a613d19 9:17 AM

Basically I'm not able to edit details on a contact when creating a new one, CiviCRM freezes up. We don't have any plug-ins or javascript installed. My WordPress version is 4.5.3. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you sure you have no WP plugins at all?

Comment: Which version of CiviCRM have you upgraded from and to?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in my console when trying to edit a participant report on an older civi install and discovered this helpful post: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=20598.0

It doesn't sound like you've got exactly the same issue, but it's an interesting clue - i.e. in my case, some db data was generating a page that had js issues, it was not a conflict problem. Of course, it might also be a red herring.

Regardless, you'll want to turn off any js aggregation and use your js debugger to dig down and figure out who's version of the datepicker is giving problems, and where the problematic data is coming from. Sometimes just looking at the arguments being passed might be a clue. My best guess is that the datepicker is gagging on some invalid date that got mangled on Civi upgrade.